# Is it possible to have a default zoom set for editors in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, editor, settings, shortcut

I want to change the default font size of the editor windows in android studio. Now, whenever I open the a new file, I do **'Ctrl + Scroll'** and set the zoom. But I don't want to be doing it every time I open a file.

**Is there any solution to this?**

Answer (score 5):

For Windows:

> 1. Go to File > Settings (ctrl + alt + s)
> 2. Modify the settings shown below

[image: Font size in Android Studio on Windows]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Go to `File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts -> Font`

On clicking font in right pane you will find <kbd>Save As..</kbd> click on that to create new Scheme and then font size option will be enable to you. change size from there and use that new scheme.

[image: new scheme]